# C# Sending email with hangfire - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, hangfire

I have installed *hangfire* to create background tasks to send emails and facing this issue when trying to fire the send-method.

```
variable 'j' of type 'x.x.Jobs.SendEmailJob' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

The send-method looks like this and it is called from my **Controller action**

```
        public Task SendAMail(string name, string email, int age, bool isNewUser, string facebookId)
        {
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue<SendEmailJob>(j => j.SendEmail(name, email, age, isNewUser, facebookId).WaitAndUnwrapException());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

I've debugged it and the values are passed correctly so i have no clue why this exception is being thrown.